# Distributions and orthogonal inner product residuum calculation

Tags: differential-geometry

I have been wondering about distributions: for given distribution $A \equiv \{a_i\}$ in tangent space $T_x \mathcal{X}$ such that we span some vector $v \in A$ as span $a_i u^i$, there is an annihilator distribution $B \equiv \{b_j\}$ such that $\langle a_i, b_j \rangle = 0$. This allows me in Mechanics to generate a $B$-constrained velocity vector $\dot{x}$, called Pfaffian systems given by equalities $\langle a_i, \dot{x} \rangle = 0$, and spanned by $b_j p^j$.

My question is: In case of a null Pfaffian condition as aforementioned, we have an inner product $\langle a_i, \dot{x} \rangle$ equal to some bounded by construction residuum map $\delta_i$, how can we build vector $c$ for the velocity vector $\dot{x} = b_j p^j + c$ such that it satisfies equality $\langle a_i, c \rangle = \delta_i$?

I suppose, for decomposition in local coordinates $c = c^k e_k$, we obtain $\langle a_i, e_k \rangle \, c^k = \delta_i$. We rename inner product $\mu_{ik}$. Since there are are less rows than columns, we must use the Moore-Penrose matrix to compute $\mu^+ \delta$. This means, the velocity vector $\dot{x}$ is given by sum $b_j p^j + \mu^+ \delta$.

Thanks!